# How to prevent "System Resource Exceeded" error in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into this error while executing the following query from Excel VBA on an Excel table that contains 28,000 records:

```
SELECT db.Station_Name, DLookUp("SPNum","[SP$]","SPEndDate=#" &
DMin("SPEndDate","[SP$]","SPEndDate>=#" & db.Sample_Date & "#") & "#") AS SP, Avg(db.Value) AS AvgQ 
FROM [database$] as db
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM [stn_list$] 
WHERE Target_Group > 0 
) AS s 
ON db.Station_Name = s.Station_Name 
GROUP BY db.Station_Name, DLookUp("SPNum","[SP$]","SPEndDate=#" & DMin("SPEndDate","[SP$]","SPEndDate>=#" & db.Sample_Date & "#") & "#")
```

When the table is reduced to 20,000 records, the error does not occur.  My computer has 12GB of RAM and minimum 50GB of virtual memory specified.  The query was tested on a second computer with the same results.  I also tested the same query in Access and it had no problem querying all 28,000 records.

I searched many posts to resolve this error but didn’t find any solutions specific to Excel VBA.  Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions for this error?  Any insights at all would be very much appreciated.

Comment: All computers has same Office version and patch level?

Comment: Same version of Office (2013). Can't seem to find what a patch level is after a google search (let me know how to find it if you need it)...our Office versions are 15.0.4981.1001 and 15.0.4953.1001, from Service Pack 1.